# How know in which router I'm when I'm connect by ethernet

Tags: ethernet, lan

When I'm connected by WLAN I can determinate in which network I'm by looking the SSID, for example:

```
$ iwgetid -r
ONOA72E
$ nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi | egrep '^yes' | cut -d: -f2
ONOA72E
```

And I can know that I'm at home because of ONOA72E is the SSID of my router.

But when I'm using LAN by ethernet I don't know what can I look in order to know if I'm using my home router or not.

Comment: Look at the endpoint of the cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your local network, and have communicated with your router, then your ARP table will have an entry for your router.  Unless you are playing very odd games with the router's MAC address, then as a string, that ARP table entry should be unique.

so assuming your router's MAC address is 11:22:33:44:55:66, a command like

`/sbin/arp -a | grep '11:22:33:44:55:66'` should find your router if its there.

If you have not communicated with the router recently, its possible the ARP table entry expired.  But you should be able to do any command that requires an access out of the local net  (say something like `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` ) and refresh that

IPV6 left as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ip(8)` command:

```
ip route list
```

gives the (default) routes for each interface.

(The legacy command for this is `route(8)`).